# Python BeautifulSoup web-scraping Tripadvisor view a review

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, data-analysis

So I am new to web scraping and trying to view list of reviews for a particular hotel.
I am initially trying to view for a particular review by selecting a particular class, and I am not getting any output, even when I try to check the status code of the request, I don't get any output. I believe my code is taking really long to run.

Does web scraping take time to run or there is a problem with my code?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'
    }

url = "https://www.tripadvisor.ca/Hotel_Review-g154913-d1587398-Reviews-Le_Germain_Hotel_Calgary-Calgary_Alberta.html"
req = requests.get(url, headers)

print (req.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

review = soup.find_all(class_="XllAv H4 _a").get_text()
print(review)
```

Comment: may be your internet slow as your code works

Comment: @SuraJS Wow, please is there a way I can see the output you got, thank you?

Comment: `Output` I've been going to the Germain Calgary every year for a birthday weekend retreat for years now. It's a wonderful respite: the staff is gracious, the rooms lovely, the location

Comment: @SurajS So you suggest its the internet speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed few `headers` `keys` and some `requests` parameters
i got error on `.get_text()` so replaced with other

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        'accept': '*/*',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'accept-language': 'en,mr;q=0.9',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36'}

url = "https://www.tripadvisor.ca/Hotel_Review-g154913-d1587398-Reviews-Le_Germain_Hotel_Calgary-Calgary_Alberta.html"
req = requests.get(url,headers=headers,timeout=5,verify=False)
print (req.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

#review = soup.find_all(class_="XllAv H4 _a").get_text()
#print(review)
for x in soup.body.find_all(class_="XllAv H4 _a"):
    print(x.text)
```